# How can $\mathbb{R}P^3$ be homeomorphic to (a quotient of) the 3D unit ball?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, projective-space

Let $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : ||x|| \le 1 \}$. I have seen it claimed that $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is homeomorphic (indeed, diffeomorphic) to $B$ where for $x \in \partial B$, $x$ is identified with $-x$.

I understand how this would work if $B$ were replaced by $S^2$. You would map a line in $\mathbb{R}P^3$ to its normalized direction vector. However, this map fails to be a homeomorphism for (the quotient of)$B$, because it is not surjective. How can we get a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}P^3$ and $B$?

Comment: Going down a dimension, $\mathbb{R}P^2$ can be seen as a disk $D^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with antipodes on its boundary circle identified. The homeomorphism between the quotient-of-$S^2$ version of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and the quotient-of-$D^2$ version of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is given by projecting the hemisphere down flat into the plane. The same thing works projecting the quotient-of-$S^3$ version of $\mathbb{R}P^3$ down to the quotient-of-$D^3$ version of $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: Maybe the dimensions are confusing: in the most common notation, the projectivization of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or $S^2$ mod antipodes) is $\mathbb{R}P^2$, and the projectivization of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (or $S^3$ mod antipodes) is $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: @Dennis I understand now, thank you so much!

Comment: @Dennis And indeed, I did get confused by the dimensions.

Comment: @user56202 Then it would be a good idea if you answer your own question.